# Can Ganglia's gmond be configured so that it doesn't need to be restarted if the Ganglia server is restarted?

Tags: monitoring, ganglia

I use [ganglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganglia_(software)) to monitor my computer cluster:

[image]

([source of the image](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/introduction-to-ganglia-on-ubuntu-14-04))

When I restart the Ganglia server, the `gmond` daemon on the other servers in the cluster stop sending information to the Ganglia server. I have to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ganglia-monitor restart
```

on each server.

Can Ganglia's gmond be configured so that it doesn't need to be restarted if the Ganglia server is restarted?

I use:

- Ganglia Web Frontend version 3.6.1
- Ganglia Web Backend (gmetad) version 3.6.0
- RRDtool version 1.4.7.
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x64 server

Comment: I'm observing the same behaviour, and as far as I can tell, the gmonds still multicast their information, and the gmond on the master still receives all metrics, but they do not make it into the XML that can be obtained from port 8649.